# why NoReverseMatch in django admin change_form

Tags: python, django

in my admin.py i have:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(AggregationProxyProviderAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = patterns('', 
        url(r'^(\d+)/import_proxies/$',
            self.admin_site.admin_view(self.import_proxies_from_file), 
            name="import_proxies", 
        ), 
    )
    return my_urls + urls
```

in change_form.html i have

```
<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'import_proxies' original.pk|admin_urlquote %}" class="btn importlink">
```

and i got error:

```
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'aggregation_aggregationproxyprovider_import_proxies' with arguments '(1L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

could somebody explain where is problem?
thanks

Comment: [Does your template include {% load admin_urls %} towards the top?](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19661)

Answer (score 0):

solution is to name url like this: aggregation_aggregationproxyprovider_import_proxies